# When to use the tkinter menubutton

Tags: python, tkinter

I am learning to build a simple application with Python 2.7 and tkinter and I am I a bit confused when it comes to creating the parent window. I have managed to create a window and dropdown menu, here is the code:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Root(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        #initialize menu
        self.config(menu=MenuBar(self))


class MenuBar(tk.Menu):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Menu.__init__(self, parent)

        filemenu = tk.Menu(self, tearoff=False)
        self.add_cascade(label="File",underline=0, menu=filemenu)
        filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=self.callback)
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", underline=1, command=self.quit)

    def quit(self):
        sys.exit(0)

    def callback(self):
        print "called the callback!"

root = Root()
root.mainloop()
```

It all works and I was happy with it until I stumbled upon the **menuButton** while reading the [tkk api](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ttk.html).

I have been googling an I can't seem to get a clear answer on what the menubutton is and when it should be used.

So, my question is:
When should I be using the menuButton and should it be used instead of the Menu and .add_cascade features?

Comment: I have no idea when you would want to use the menu button, but I can tell you it's not a replacement for the menu (menubar) and drop down menus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally you won't  use the `Menubutton` class. It's mostly only useful if you want a button with an attached menu in the middle of a GUI. For example, the `OptionMenu` class uses an instance of the `Menubutton` class for the button. Most modern UIs don't use menus in this way.

Comment: This answer was four years ago. What do modern UIs use today instead of drop down menus?

Comment: @josch: I'm not sure I understand the question. Modern UIs can still use drop down menus (though, it's debatable if "modern UIs" use tkinter at all). Usually they are on a menubar or they are on a right-click menu. If you need a drop-down menu in the middle of a UI (ie: not a menubar, not a right-click menu), you can still use a `Menubutton` widget.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `Menubutton` widget has been declared obsolete since Tk8.0

Comment: @josch: what do you mean by "declared obsolete"? Who is making this declaration?

Comment: It's written in the tkinter source code for 19 years now: https://github.com/python/cpython/blame/master/Lib/tkinter/__init__.py#L3393 The message was added in commit 5917ecb0a4fa1c5e7ca8f73a0b17d4f5e23e0291

Comment: @josch: interesting. I have no idea what they mean by that, other than like I wrote in my answer, it's usually more common to associate a menu with the window. I think that's more of a personal opinion than a statement of fact. The menubutton is still used to create the `Optionmenu` widget. The official tcl/tk documentation and source code doesn't say anything about it being obsolete.